# Unable to launch browser from WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

When I try to launch browser from WSL, it provides the following message:

```bash
Command '/usr/bin/x-www-browser' requires the chromium snap to be installed.
Please install it with:

snap install chromium
```

Running `snap install chromium` gets me:

```bash
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/chromium: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

Comment: How are you launching the browser ?

Comment: For example, [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) should open up the browser to allow for GitHub authentication.

Comment: Just for curiosity sake?  Why use the browser on that side of the wall?  Why not simply use the one that already works?  And.. the question is totally fair.. I am just curious about the motive.

Comment: You must be on Windows 11 for this to work and the distribution must come  from the Microsoft Store (which one is yours?). Exit wsl  via `wsl --shutdown` and run `wsl --update`. Run wsl again and check that the file `/etc/wsl.conf` contains just 2 lines: `[boot]` and `systemd=true` (if not change it and do  `wsl --shutdown` again). Now try snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by uninstalling chromium:

```bash
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium/
```